# Is there an R function to find a value which is not NA and fill column with that value till nex not NA value?

Tags: r

Hey guys I am trying to get my Code running where I read in multiple Excel files, with all Sheets into a dataframe.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(fs)
library(readxl)
library(xlsx)
library(easyGgplot2)
setwd(choose.dir())

read_multiple_excel <- function(path) {
  path %>%
    excel_sheets() %>% 
    set_names() %>% 
    map_df(read_excel, path = path)
}


data_df <- dir_ls(regexp = "xls") %>% 
  map_df(read_multiple_excel,
         .id = "data_name")

str(data_df)
```

The code works so far but, in that dataframe  I have a column with the title ...18. It contains NA Values and the second entry in that column is a text like "3a". I want to rename all NA values to 3a until I reach the next text Input for example 3b. Unfortunatly also the first NA before 3a should be named 3a and the first NA before 3b should also be 3b. This should be done until the column is finished.

Example:

```
...18   ---->   ...18
NA               "3a" 
"3a"             "3a"
NA               "3a"
NA               "3b"
"3b"             "3b"
NA               "3b"
NA               "3c"
"3c"             "3c"
```

I am thankful for every hint how to arcieve that task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a `for` loop combined with `dplyr::coalesce`:

```
x <- c(NA, "3a", NA, NA, "3b", NA, NA, "3c")
x2 <- x

for (i in which(is.na(x))){
  if(i == 1){
   x2[i] <- x2[i + 1] 
  }else{
    x2[i] <- dplyr::coalesce(x2[i + 1], x2[i-1])
  }
}

x2
# [1] "3a" "3a" "3a" "3b" "3b" "3b" "3c" "3c"
```

There is a function in **`dplyr`** called [`fill`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/fill.html), which gets close to what you want, but is not perfect.

Comment: thank you, that saved my data Analysis :)